# Problemas al consultar por rango de fechas en firestore desde c#

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, firestore

les comento.
estoy tratando de consultar por rango de fecha mis registros de firestore. lo hago mediante este codigo.

```
DateTime fechaConsultainicio = dtpFechaInicio.Value;
DateTime value = DateTime.SpecifyKind(fechaConsultainicio, DateTimeKind.Utc);
Timestamp fechaConsultaStampInicio = Timestamp.FromDateTime(value);

DateTime fechaConsultaFin = dtpFechaFin.Value;
DateTime value2 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(fechaConsultaFin, DateTimeKind.Utc);
Timestamp fechaConsultaStampFin = Timestamp.FromDateTime(value2);

  CollectionReference citiesRef = db.Collection("Consulta");
  Query query = citiesRef.WhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("fechaConsulta", fechaConsultaStampInicio).WhereLessThanOrEqualTo("fechaConsulta", fechaConsultaStampFin);
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.GetSnapshotAsync();
```

El problema es que el WhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo() no esta funcionando bien, lo esta haciendo como un WhereGreaterThan(), es decir que no me trae los registros del mismo día ingresado, sino posteriores.
Por ejemplo, si pongo que mi fecha de inicio sea el 2 de marzo y la final el 5, se me listan únicamente lo registros entre el 3 y el 5 de marzo, para obtener los del 2 de marzo me tocaría poner en la fecha de inicio  1 de marzo.

A que se puede deber esto?.

Comment: Es posible que las fechas tengan tambien la hora? Si fuera asi, es posible que la comparación del equal fallase.

Comment: Si pues es un timestamp, entonces si se almacena con la hora. Pero entonces por que el WhereLessThanOrEqualTo() sin funciona?  Hay alguna manera de solucionarlo?

Comment: La verdad nunca he usado `WhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo`  pero entiendo que no compara solo las fechas,sino tambien la hora,por lo que para que sean iguales las horas deberian coincidir al milisegundo. Como solucion,puede usar otro metodo que compare solo fechas,o simplemente restar un dia a la fecha que comparas para que obtenga el rango correcto

Comment: De hecho, veo que ese metodo compara como string, con lo que no sería muy adecuado para comparar fechas. Lamentablemente no tengo experiencia en firebase para recomendarte otro metodo mejor, pero simplemente restando un a la fecha de comparacion debería servir